# Behavior of crow pair, larger crow eats the food, not leaving any for smaller buddy

Tags: birds, bird-behaviour, crows

There are a couple of crows that come around regularly, they come as a pair. One is larger than the other. Perhaps a couple? or parent and youth? or adult and older parent?

When providing nuts/seeds to them the larger one will eagerly eat it all without leaving any for the smaller one, who hangs back a little.

I feel sad that the smaller one isn't getting any of the food. However, I have no idea what the relationship is or behavioral norms. Would the larger crow be regurgitating the food for the smaller one later? or the small one is just hoping for scraps? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess at an answer to your question.  I think you may be strewing the food over too small an area, so that the smaller crow has to come too close to the larger crow to feed.  I suggest you try strewing the food over a wider area, so that it is not possible for one bird to monopolize the area.

I often see cooperation among crows.  One crow will watch the patio, and when I put food out, he/she caws the rest of the flock in to share the bounty.